# My touchpad is not supported by the kernel

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad, acer, aspire

The kernel of Xubuntu 18.04 does not support the touchpad of my notebook, an [Acer Aspire ES1-522-4682](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/6268?b=1).

`uname -a` shows:

```
Linux Aspire-ES1-522 4.18.0-25-generic #26~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 27 07:28:31 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How can I fix it, or ask developers for support to add my touchpad to the kernel?

P.S. "Kernel" is "Ядро" in Russian, hope I translated that thing well.

Comment: lease get the kernel version with `uname -a` , click [edit] here, and add the kernel version to your original question. Please do not use Add Comment; use [edit] instead. Then consider installing the newer kernels (which does not remove what you have now)http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/06/install-linux-kernel-4-17-ubuntu-18-04 http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/10/linux-kernel-4-19-released-install-ubuntu/ and http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/05/linux-kernel-5-1-released-install-in-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a kernel issue.

Try changing your touchpad settings from Advanced to Basic on BIOS menu.